# defined variables return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code but when I run the code, it returns as undefined. I have no idea why this happens!

```
function loadServiceXml(){
    $.get("/xml/ServiceUrls.xml", function(xml){
        return $.xml2json(xml);
    });
}

function getMajorGroups(){
    //get the base element to be created.
    var jsonXmlObject;
    jsonXmlObject = loadServiceXml();
    var element = $('.item-group-button').first();

}
```

The response returns the xml file without any issues, and when I break and check the values of the variables using firebug it returns as undefined.

Comment: AJAX callbacks are asynchronous. Run the code that you want to execute _inside_ the callback. This really must be the most asked question in JavaScript.

Comment: "when I run the code" - what code do you run? What do you mean "the response returns the xml file without any issues"? What response?

Comment: your loadServiceXml doesn't return anything, only the anonymous function you pass to get() returns something

Answer (score 1):

`$.get` is an asynchronous operation. So what actually happens is that your `loadServiceXml()` method returns `undefined` since it does not explicitly return anything. You have to do the work you intend to inside the function you pass to `$.get`

```
function loadServiceXml(){
    $.get("/xml/ServiceUrls.xml", function(xml){
        // Process the response here
    });
}
```

Comment: I convert the returned xml object to a json object and I tried assigning it to a variable but that too returns undefined!

Comment: Returning anything from the $.get won't help. You have to process the xml inside the callback (or delegate to another function).

Comment: well then I use xml2json to process the xml and parse it to a json object! but how can I get that object out to another function! or maybe store in a global variable!

Comment: That's how async code works. Instead of the other method depending on the value as an external variable, pass the processed json to your method inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` from your `$.get` callback doesn't return a value out of `loadServiceXml`. That function won't ever return anything! Additionally, you've got an asynchronous call that you're attempting to treat as a synchronous call.

Instead, try passing a callback function to loadServiceXml to be invoked with the returned value once the value comes back:

```
function loadServiceXml(callback){
    $.get("/xml/ServiceUrls.xml", function(xml){
        callback($.xml2json(xml));
    });
}

function getMajorGroups(){
    //get the base element to be created.
    loadServiceXml(function(jsonXmlObject) {
        var element = $('.item-group-button').first();
    }));
}
```

Here, you pass an anonymous function to `loadServiceXml`, which is then called and passed the XML object as a parameter once the object is available. So once your call completes, execution jumps back into that anonymous function in `getMajorGroups`.